# Offline maps with QtMobility location on meego/N9?

Tags: qt, maps, meego, ovi, meego-harmattan

I would like to use ovi maps in offline mode in one application for meego-harmattan.
According to the qml Map element documentation, there is a Map.OfflineMode option for the connectivityMode, but this option doesnt work in practice.

Searching around i found some people claiming that offline ovi maps are possible on meego-harmattan, others (https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTMOBILITY-1116) saying that they should be, but the plugin that allows it is not easily available.

Now, this last information is dated oct 2011. I wonder whether with 2 more updates of the framework (and firmware of the phone), it became possible to use offline maps?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokia/Ovi maps don't support/allow caching afaik. But check the OSM tile support package,http://xf.iksaif.net/dev/qtm-geoservices-extras.html it seems to support caching of map tiles.